# solving stochastic differential equation - how to start

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Can someone please help to solve the following SDE:
$$
dX_t=\cos(t)\,dW_t-\tan(t)X_t\,dt,
~~
X_0=0?
$$
My idea is to start in this way:
$$
X_t = 0 + \int \cos(t)\,dW_t - \int \tan(t)X_t\,dt ,
$$
but here I have the problem with $X_t$ on the right side.

Is my beginning of solving even correct? Should I start in different way?

thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You get a directly solvable equation if you apply the Ito transformation theorem (chain rule for SDE) to
$$
Y_t=F(t,X_t)=\frac{X_t}{\cos(t)}.
$$